# Change name and value of attribute `_class` with Spring Data Couchbase

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I changed the way that Spring Data Couchbase writes its `_class` attribute following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39037452/3202612). Now, if I save an object of class `com.package.entity.User`, my document looks like:

```
{
    ...
    "_type": "user"
}
```

My point is, when I use query methods like `public Long countByAdminIsTrue()`, the request generated by Spring is the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `myBucket` WHERE (`admin` = TRUE) AND `_type` = "com.package.entity.User"
```

Instead of the result I expect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `myBucket` WHERE (`admin` = TRUE) AND `_type` = "user"
```

Here is my `CouchbaseTypeMapper` doint this work:

```
public class CustomCouchbaseTypeMapper extends DefaultTypeMapper<CouchbaseDocument> implements CouchbaseTypeMapper {
    public CustomCouchbaseTypeMapper() {
        super(new CustomCouchbaseDocumentTypeAliasAccessor());
    }

    @Override
    public String getTypeKey() {
        return "_type";
    }

    public static final class CustomCouchbaseDocumentTypeAliasAccessor implements TypeAliasAccessor<CouchbaseDocument> {
        @Override
        public Object readAliasFrom(CouchbaseDocument source) {
            return source.get("_type");
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTypeTo(CouchbaseDocument sink, Object alias) {
            String typeName = StringUtils.typeNameFromFullClassName((String) alias);
            sink.put("_type", typeName);
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried to define a `ConfigurableTypeInformationMapper` in the constructor with my entities, it doesn't help. 
How can I make Spring Data to use my custom type name and value when it generates a query based on a query method?

Comment: Ensure you it's not a typo but `formattedTypeName` is not defined

Comment: Why are you avoiding using a fully qualified classname?

Comment: Because this bucket is shared with others apps which are not using Spring Data / are not Java apps / does not have their entities in the same package / etc.

Comment: Note after about 1 year as a developer on this application : do not share buckets with other apps. Use web services instead.